# It's not showing full content for posts pages in wordpress "[...]" while customing some changes in the style.css file

Tags: php, css, wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRb9X.png)I was trying to do some changes in the style.css file but something wrong I did due to which the content for all the posts in the site it start showing "[...]" after a small content that too not in formatted form but simple.
Will be very great full for any find of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that with CSS. It was trimmed the content by `the_excerpt()` in Wordpress. Ref [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/).

Used `the_content()` to show full content of post. Ref [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/)

Comment: Can I please know in what is the file name as I was unable to find post-template.php file in  theme files on wordpress dashboard as given in the ref link provided by you

Comment: I am working for a someone ,I am not using it on localhost.I can only edit files for theme as far as I know.Can you please suggest me something else to resolve the problem

Comment: You can find it in `single.php` or `content.php`.

Comment: Welcome, choose my answer if it helped so other people can know this one is solved :)